# Does Raj Koothrappali ever get married?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-big-bang-theory

In the final episode of "The Big Bang Theory" (S12E24), it seems like the creators of the show wanted to "come full circle" with the all of the characters. 
Some examples of this are:

> 1. Sheldon and Amy getting a Nobel Prize,
>  2. Leonard and Penny expecting a baby,
>  3. Howard and Bernadette becoming used to the fact that they are parents.

During that episode,

> Raj meets an actress on the way to Sweden, and she comes along with him to the Nobel award ceremony.

Later on, Raj tries holding hands with her and although she refuses and says that it's "not a date", it seems like she has some interest in him. Is this a subtle nod from the creators that Raj may have finally found his wife, supported by the fact that Raj would have a nice ending like the rest of the characters, or is this just another temporary girlfriend that will dump him?

Comment: As Paulie_D says below, **NO**. I agree with you that creators rushing into fill the whole circle by forcing character to get married without proper layout. but for some reason at the end they abandoned it. So for the show's run, Raj is still single until the nobel price ceremony. After that what happens, we don't know. Also Geller is just hanging out with them just for the ceremony, probably as a friend while Raj mistakenly and/or trying to win her kept trying to make a date with her.(most probably his love with Buffy other than his affection on real life Geller)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Unknown

**Adding to Paulie_D's answer, It's unknown if he ever gets married, but he character arc for Raj closes when he discovered that being single is OK, that friends are more important**

We should remember that in S12E22:

> [Anu](https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Anu) is in London for a convention and then gets offered a management position. She wonders what that means for them. Raj decides to go to London and propose thinking that this is his last chance for happiness, but Howard goes to the airport and convinces him to stay.

[This article](https://culturess.com/2019/05/17/why-raj-not-finding-love-on-the-big-bang-theory-series-finale-is-ok/) explains it in a really nice manner:

> Plus, Raj learned so much from his relationship with Anu — never settle just because you want something so badly, i.e. marriage and family. Yes, the series finale could’ve had Raj meet his soulmate without ever showing their happy ending, but it’s all right it didn’t happen that way.
>
> Being single is OK and that’s an important lesson Raj discovered. You don’t need someone else to be happy. And just because Raj remained single in the end doesn’t mean he’ll be alone forever.

So, he doesn't marry Anu and Sarah Michelle Gellar is already married, so Raj is left single by the end of the series.

Answer (score 2):

## No.

> Sarah Michelle Gellar starred as “herself” as opposed to playing a character. Hence, she and Raj attended the Nobel Prize ceremony as friends. Gellar is married in real life, **which is why there couldn't be anything romantic between the two**.

The creators [explained](https://www.cinemablend.com/television/2471937/how-the-big-bang-theorys-series-finale-landed-sarah-michelle-gellars-cameo):

> > "There is a line in there where she says to him, ‘This is not a date.’ We’re aware Sarah Michelle Gellar is fairly famously married in real life [to Freddie Prinze Jr.], so **we didn’t want there to be any confusion there."**

Comment: *Gellar is married in real life, which is why there couldn't be anything romantic between the two.* this seemed not true. I've seen numerous situations two married actors have romantic relationships. Geller saying this isn't a date simply means that she have no interest in Raj. IMO. Even though she is playing herself and saying this is not a date is simply she disn't want to have a date with Raj. see her reaction on her face when she say it

Answer (score 2):

[Showrunner Steve Holland explained](https://tvline.com/2019/05/09/big-bang-theory-recap-raj-anu-breakup-season-12-episode-22/) Raj's marital status before the finale:

> “The Anu-Raj relationship was a fun part of the season and, as close as it was, she wasn’t quite the perfect one for him — and we want Raj to end up with the perfect woman,” explains showrunner Steve Holland of the decision to split them up. “As great as Anu was, and as great as the actress Rati [Gupta] was, she was such a different person. It started to feel like it wasn’t who you wanted to see Raj end up with. **You want for Raj to have that sort of fairytale romance that he’s dreamed about all these years.**
>
> “And maybe someday in the future he still does have [the fairytale],” Holland adds. “But **we didn’t feel like we needed to tie all of these characters up in a relationship bow**.”

Comment: I strongly disagree with this part : **The Anu-Raj relationship was a fun part**, that was not fun, not any good IMO

Comment: @Vishwa Agreed. That relationship seemed so forced, like the show-runners wanted to plaster a partner to Raj.

Comment: @Sandun absolutely, it's very hard to look at..